# Listbox "IsSelected" binding only partially working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` that I populate dynamically via a binding (this is defined in a `DataTemplate`, which is why the binding is somewhat unusual):

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ResultList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Label Content="{Binding Object}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Each `ListBoxItem`'s `IsSelected` property is bound to an `IsSelected` property on a custom object.

When I select individual `ListBoxItem`s, the binding works properly - the custom object's `IsSelected` property is updated in my ViewModel.  However, if I select all of the `ListBoxItem`s with a Ctrl+A command, only the currently visible `ListBoxItem`s (those that are currently in my scrolling viewport) update their ViewModel bindings.  On the frontend, all the `ListBoxItem`s appear to be selected, and the `ListBox.SelectedItems.Count` property on the container `ListBox` shows that all items are selected.

Furthermore, as I scroll through the `ListBox` after selecting all `ListBoxItem`s with Ctrl+A, the bindings are successfully updated when each `ListBoxItem` is scrolled into view.

Why does this binding seem to be only partially working?  Is there a better way to handle the binding of the `IsSelected` property when large numbers of `ListBoxItems` can be selected simultaneously?

**Edit:**
This behavior doesn't happen exclusively with the Ctrl+A command - I get the same results when selecting all the items using a shift+click.

Comment: I would not depend on the UI to do that, you'd rather put a `KeyBinding` and do that in the ViewModel, or put some code behind and delegate the selection logic to the VM. Or put a Behavior or something that reacts to that key combination.

Comment: @HighCore - The problem doesn't happen with the Select All command exclusively;  the same problem occurs when I select every item using a shift+click.

Comment: I ran into this same kind of issue.  I just gave up and used a binding to [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) as the Argument for the Click handler on a button, and called it a day (you could also use it as the CommandParameter for a Command).  It's just not worth the performance hit to turn off virtualization when the list gets long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the behavior you're seeing is to due to `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` which is `True` by default when binding to `ItemsSource` of `ListBox`

if you for eg set your `ListBox` such as:

```
<ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ResultList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
```

or

```
<ListBox ...>
  ...
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

then you should see all your bound items have their `IsSelected` updated accordingly with Ctrl+A or Shift + ...

Properties such as `Count` of the collection even with virtualization would report the correct value to accommodate for things like computing the required `ScrollBar.Height`. Items which are outside the View-port do not get rendered hence no bindings are in effect on them until they actually get used.

Comment: It worked. But what is this virtualization and why it caused the problem?

Comment: "The standard layout system creates item containers and computes layout for each item associated with a list control. The word "virtualize" refers to a technique by which a subset of UI elements are generated from a larger number of data items based on which items are visible on-screen. Generating many UI elements when only a few elements might be on the screen can hurt performance. The VirtualizingStackPanel calculates the number of visible items and works with the ItemContainerGenerator from an ItemsControl (such as ListBox or ListView) to create UI elements only for visible items."